# Get a count of total documents with MongoDB aggregation when using limit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
const search = await searchAgent.aggregate([
    {$match: {id: Number(fid), status: {$regex: status, $options: 'i'}}},
    {$sort: {[order_by]: order == 'desc' ? -1 : 1}},
    {$skip: skip},
    {$limit: pagelimit},
])
```

Here I need to get the total number of documents matching the query. As I am using the limit I can't get the total count of documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const search = await searchAgent.aggregate([
  { $match: { fid: Number(fid), ...agent_details, } },
  { $facet: {
    data: [{
      $sort: {
        [filter.order_by]: order == 'desc' ? -1 : 1 }
      }, {
        $skip: skip
      }, {
        $limit: pagelimit
      }
    ],
    total: [{$count: "total"}]
  }}
])
```

Here I got the result by using the facet method inside the query. I had given the sort and limit inside the facet method, and given the total count outside the facet. So the limit won't affect getting the total count of documents.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: sure I had added

Answer (score 0):

The common approach to solve this is to use the [$facet](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) stage, then one pipeline is used to match with the proper `skip` and `limit` and one pipeline for the count.
like so:

```
const searchResults = await searchAgent.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            id: Number(fid),
            status: {$regex: status, $options: 'i'}
        }
    },
    {
        $facet: {
            results: [
                {
                    $sort: {
                        [order_by]: order == 'desc' ? -1 : 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    $skip: skip
                },
                {
                    $limit: pagelimit
                },
            ],
            count: [
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: null,
                        count: {
                            $sum: 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
])

const search = searchResults[0]?.results;
const searchCount = searchResults[0].count[0].count
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8PXSTfyEsqm)